# Prove $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/H$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/7\Bbb Z$ (isomorphism theorem)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/H$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/7\Bbb Z$
where $H = \{(3n+2m, 4n + 5m)\}$.

**Things I tried**

I understand this is testing me on the isomorphism theorem.
My goal is to construct a homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/7\Bbb Z$ who's kernel is H.
But, I am having a hard time doing so.

If I set $f((a, b)) = (a + b) \mod 7$ then certainly $f(H)$ = 0.
But $f((7, 0)) = 0$ and $(7, 0)$ is not in $H$ so $H$ is only a subset of the kernel.

Constructing a homomorphism the opposite direction (breaking 0-6 into two components) seems difficult.

**Other constraints**

I imagine there may be a trick since the group has prime order,
but I am looking to understand a more general method. I have seen several variations of this problem.

Comment: Is your definition of $H$ correct? Every pair $(a,b)$ with $a,b$ have the same parity is in $H$ (just take $n=(3b-5a)/2$ and $m=2a-b$), hence $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/H\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @withoutfeather my mistake. I corrected it. I had transposed two of the coefficients.

Comment: $(7,0)=(3×(5)+2×(-4),4×(5)+5×(-4))$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby good catch. Let me think about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of $H$ as follows:
$$H=\left\{n\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix}+m\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\end{bmatrix}  \, \left.\right| m,n, \in \Bbb{Z}\right\}$$
Note that 
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\underbrace{a\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix}-a\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\end{bmatrix}}_{\in H}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\a+b\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix} \equiv \begin{bmatrix}0\\a+b\end{bmatrix} \pmod{H}.$$
So your map
$$f(a,b)=a+b \mod{7}$$
will work.

Comment: Having trouble interpreting the second line. Should one of the $a$ be a $b$?

Comment: @JustinMeiners The coefficients are correct. The idea is that we can view $H$ as being "spanned" (integer linear combination) by the two vectors $\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}2\\5\end{bmatrix}$. So just like we do mod operation in integers, where we take out a multiple of the modulus. Here also we are doing the same, taking out a linear combination of the vectors generating $H$.

Comment: @JustinMeiners In fact, we could have also written $$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=-b\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}a+b\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Got it. thanks for follow up.